# Folder Missing in /tmp

Tags: bash, shell

I created a folder named "UA_Automation" under the location /tmp in one of my colleague machine. The folder "UA_Automation" is completely missing now in /tmp. My colleague have not removed.

Can there be any reason for disappearing file from /tmp? This is happening for the second time!

Comment: Are you rebooted you system?

Comment: Which OS/distribution/version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As its name suggests, `/tmp` is for temporary storage. Its contents do not persist across reboots, as it is generally a RAM disk, and will be cleared every few days depending on how often it's been configured to. (On Ubuntu, there's a system variable called `TMPTIME` that changes this. If it's 0, then `/tmp` is only cleared on reboot.)

Comment: No way from retrieve the folder? Also, I would like to know when might have, possibly, the  folder might have vanished...

Comment: There is no way to retrieve the folder, it has been deleted from a RAM disk. You can't know when it was deleted unless you have a timestamp for when the tmpfs clear script was called.